# Parsing values in a text file

Tags: python

I'm kind of a beginner to all this and am trying to parse an organized text file.

The text file resembles the following:

```
blahblahblahblahbblahb
blahblahblahblahblahblah
Variable: A Variable1: B Variable2: C
blah blah blah
```

I'm trying to extract the values after Variable, Variable1, Variable2.

My idea is to try and split the line with the variables into new lines for each "Variable" and then delete everything else not starting with Variable/Variable1/Variable2, then convert it into a table.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I should approach this in a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
fields=line.split()
values = []
for k in range(len(fields)):
    if fields[k].startswith("Variable"):
        values.append(fields[k+1])
```

Then values is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to save data to a text file then I suggest you check out [JSON](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/json/) files as they are a lot easier to parse.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex module.

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"(Variable\d*): (\w+)")

with open('pathToFile') as f:
    fileString = f.read()
    data = pattern.findAll(fileString)
```

this will give you something like this :

```
>>> data
[('Variable', 'A'), ('Variable1', 'B'), ...]
```

As it's been said elsewhere though, if you are trying to store data or write a configuration file, you should use the [JSON module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) or install the excellent [yaml package](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation)

Any one of those would give you a much more robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the lines, then try:

```
result = filter(lambda item: line.split(' ').index(item)%2!=0,line.split(' '))
print(result)
```

If your want to do task of filtering, mapping, reducing etc. Please check out lambda function, easy to understand and use.
[Python Document of lambda](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~erdmann/mse350/topics/list_comprehensions.html)